# Changing supervisor processes dynamically through PHP APIs

Tags: php, supervisord

I have setup [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which I use to manager my worker processes.
Now, I want to dynamically change the processes (stop some processes and start new ones) through the use of PHP APIs.

I found this [library](https://github.com/supervisorphp) which seems to be useful for what I am trying. Specifically, I am using [this](https://github.com/supervisorphp/configuration) to change the configuration and [this](https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor) to manage supervisor.

I have set this library up and have the following sample code which seems to work well (from [here](https://github.com/supervisorphp/configuration) and [here](https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor))

```
<?php    

require './vendor/autoload.php';
use Supervisor\Supervisor;
use Supervisor\Connector\XmlRpc;
use fXmlRpc\Client;
use fXmlRpc\Transport\HttpAdapterTransport;
use Ivory\HttpAdapter\Guzzle5HttpAdapter;

use Supervisor\Configuration\Configuration;
use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Supervisord;
use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Program;
use Indigo\Ini\Renderer;


//Create GuzzleHttp client
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['auth' => ['user', '123']]);

// Pass the url and the guzzle client to the XmlRpc Client
$client = new Client(
    'http://127.0.0.1:9001/RPC2',
    new HttpAdapterTransport(new Guzzle5HttpAdapter($guzzleClient))
);

// Pass the client to the connector
// See the full list of connectors bellow
$connector = new XmlRpc($client);

$supervisor = new Supervisor($connector);

$processes = $supervisor->getAllProcesses();

foreach ($processes as $key => $processInfo) {
    echo $processInfo . "\r\n";
}

try{
$supervisor->stopProcess('video_convert_02');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "\r\n Exception-> " . $e->getMessage();
}


$config = new Configuration;
$renderer = new Renderer;

$section = new Supervisord(['identifier' => 'supervisor']);
$config->addSection($section);

$section = new Program('test', ['command' => 'cat']);
$config->addSection($section);

echo "\r\n Config \r\n" . $renderer->render($config->toArray());

//Not sure how to use this config information to launch supervisor processes.

?>
```

The output to this is as follows:

```
pdf_convert_00
pdf_convert_01
video_convert_00
video_convert_01
video_convert_02
video_convert_03

 Exception-> BAD_NAME: video_convert_02
 Config
[supervisord]
identifier = supervisor

[program:test]
command = cat
```

I have two questions here:

1. I dont understand why it throws an exception, when I try to stop the process and
2. How do I use the config information to launch new processes?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use this library but "BAD_NAME" error means there is no such process with this name in your configuration.

Btw if you need only to call Supervisor API you can use [SupervisorXMLRPC library](https://github.com/ihor/SupervisorXMLRPC). Which simply forwards your requests to the Supervisor.

```
$supervisor = new \Supervisor\Api('127.0.0.1', 9001, 'user', '123');

$processes = $supervisor->getAllProcessInfo();
foreach ($processes as $processInfo) {
    print_r($processInfo);
}

try {
    $supervisor->stopProcess('video_convert_02');
}
catch (\Supervisor\ApiException $e){
    echo "\r\n Exception-> " . $e->getMessage();
}
```